# How to change the value of a variable in a section of a file only?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am looking for help with an example usage of the 'sed' command. i want to change value of variable in section in the text file , in this example i want to change value of aaa in section [aaa] to new value, how to change it using sed or another command .

```
[aaa]
a= b 
c= aaa 
e = f 


[bbb]
a = b
c = aaa
e = f
```

Comment: Do you want to change it in both the section header `[aaa]` and the assignment `c= aaa` - or just the latter? do you want to possibly change multiple instances or just the first?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```bsh
$ sed '/^\[aaa\]/,/^\[/{/^\[/b; s/aaa/NEW/}' file.ini
[aaa]
a= b 
c= NEW 
e = f 


[bbb]
a = b
c = aaa
e = f
```

#### How it works

The overall command looks like

```
/^\[aaa\]/,/^\[/{...}
```

The pair of two regexes separated by a comma, `/^\[aaa\]/,/^\[/` defines a range of lines starting with a line that starts with `[aaa]` and ending with the next line that starts with `[`.  For any line in that range, but *only* lines in that range, the commands in curly braces are executed.  Those commands are:

1. `/^\[/b`

   The regex `/^\[/` looks for lines that start with `[`.  For those lines, the command `b` is executed.  `b` stands for branch and tells sed to branch past (skip) the rest of the commands.
2. `s/aaa/NEW/`

   For any other line in the range, this tells sed to replace any occurrence of `aaa` with `NEW`.

In more detail, `/^\[aaa\]/` is a regex that a literal `[` at the start of a line followed by three `a` followed by a literal `]`.  The `[` and `]` must be escaped with a backslash because, without the backslash, `[` and `]` are regex active characters.  The regex `/^\[` matches any line that starts with `[` where `^` is a regex-active character that matches at the start of a line and `\[` matches a literal `[`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest `perl` for this - since it supports both in-place replacement (the `-i` option) and a *paragraph mode* e.g.

```
$ perl -00pe 's/aaa/XYZ/g if /^\[aaa\]/' file.ini
[XYZ]
a= b 
c= XYZ 
e = f 

[bbb]
a = b
c = aaa
e = f
```

If you want to replace `aaa` within the section but not in the `[aaa]` section header, then you can exclude the latter with lookarounds:

```
$ perl -00pe 's/(?<!\[)aaa(?!\])/XYZ/g if /^\[aaa\]/' file.ini
[aaa]
a= b 
c= XYZ 
e = f 

[bbb]
a = b
c = aaa
e = f
```

To perform the replacement in-place:

```
perl -i -00pe 's/(?<!\[)aaa(?!\])/XYZ/g if /^\[aaa\]/' file.ini
```